# nosetests with namespace packages

Tags: python, nosetests

I have two packages in the same namespace with tests, the structure is like this:

```
Package-1/namespace/__init__.py
Package-1/namespace/module1/__init__.py
Package-2/namespace/__init__.py
Package-2/namespace/module2/__init__.py
Package-2/tests/foo_test.py
```

Package 1 is properly installed using `pip`. Now Package 2 depends on Package 1, so `foo_test` contains the line

```
import namespace.module1
```

When I try to run `nosetests ./tests/foo_test.py` from the directory `Package-2` I get an import error because Python complains that it did not find `namespace.module1`. I am quite sure that the problem is that it tries to search the path `Package-2/namespace` for the directory `module1` which is of course not present. I would like Python to load `module1` from the installed packages and not search for it in the current path.

I am not entirely sure, but I think that [here](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/issues/19) a similar issue is explained but to my understanding this should have been fixed. Does anybody have an idea how to work around this? Or am I supposed to structure things differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution for this, at least in Python 3.3+. The `__init__.py` files that are present in `Package-i/namespace/` have to be deleted. I don't understand exactly why that solves the problem but it works in my case...

Comment: by deleting the `__init__.py` in the namespace folder you are deferring the package to be a native namespaced package see: https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages